# Error: Type argument 'T' doesn't conform to the bound 'Object' of the type variable 'T' on 'GetIt.call'. After migrating to Null Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm in the process of migrating over a large project to null safety and I'm coming across a strange error I'm not entirely sure how to fix.

"Error: Type argument 'T' doesn't conform to the bound 'Object' of the type variable 'T' on 'GetIt.call'."

```
class BaseView<T extends BaseProvider?> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value, Widget? child)? builder;
  final Function(T)? onModelReady;

  BaseView({this.builder, this.onModelReady});

  @override
  _BaseViewState<T> createState() => _BaseViewState<T>();
}

class _BaseViewState<T extends BaseProvider?> extends State<BaseView<T?>> {
  T model = locator<T>(); <---- This is throwing it

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.onModelReady != null) {
      widget.onModelReady!(model);
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T?>(
      create: (context) => model,
      child: Consumer<T>(builder: widget.builder!),
    );
  }
}
```

I can't find much info on this error and so far any method I've tried hasn't worked out.  Can anyone be of assistance?

I'm using Provider for state management and BaseView is what wraps all my other views during build; e.g.:

```
class EquipmentMainView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<EquipmentProvider>(
      onModelReady: (model) async {
        model.getAllFunctions();
      },..
```

Comment: [`GetIt.call>T>()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_it/latest/get_it/GetIt/call.html) expects `T` to derive from `Object` (and therefore be non-nullable).  I'm not familiar with `package:get_it` and don't know what `locator` is, but it seems like you're trying to use `GetIt.call()` with a type parameter that is potentially nullable.  You probably should change `BaseView` and `_BaseViewState` to use `T extends BaseProvider` instead.

Comment: Ah, you were correct!  Making those two changes allows it to build.  Thank you

Comment: @Swisscheese what changes did you do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting here for anyone else that might eventually run across this in the future, just changed the nullability of BaseProvider suggested by jamesdlin by changing

```
class BaseView<T extends BaseProvider?>
```

to

```
class BaseView<T extends BaseProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues when I upgraded to flutter 2.0 I made the generic methods in Generic class to explicitly extends Base class Object i.e

from:

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

class PoultryBabaRegistry<T> {
 static GetIt _getIt = GetIt.instance;

 static void register<T>(T model) {
   _getIt.registerSingleton<T extends Object >(model, signalsReady:  true);
    }
 static void remove<T>(T model) {
  _getIt.unregister<T extends Object>(instance:model);
     }
 static T getIt<T>() {
   return _getIt.get<T>();
  }
}
```

to:

```
class PoultryBabaRegistry<T extends Object> {
   static GetIt _getIt = GetIt.instance;

   static void register<T extends Object>(T model) {
    _getIt.registerSingleton<T  >(model, signalsReady: true);
    }
   static void remove<T extends Object>(T model) {
    _getIt.unregister<T>(instance:model);
   }
  static T getIt<T extends Object>() {
    return _getIt.get<T>();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this error: but the funny thing is I forgot to ***extend my class with GetXController***

hope it helps...
:)